# What DB required to make the Silverlight Business Application template work?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services, business-application

I've been trying to run the Silverlight Business Application template but it fails when I try to register.  I have SQL Express with an MSSQLSERVER instance and I've defined the standard aspnetdb created.

The error is:

```
Submit operation failed.  Unable to connect to SQL server database.

 at System.Web.DomainServices.ReflectionDomainServiceDescriptionProvider.ReflectionDomainOperationEntry.Invoke(DomainService domainService, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.DomainServices.DomainService.InvokeDomainOperationEntry(DomainOperationEntry domainOperationEntry, Object[] parameters, ChangeSetEntry operation)
   at System.Web.DomainServices.DomainService.InvokeCudOperations(ChangeSet changeSet)
   at System.Web.DomainServices.DomainService.ExecuteChangeSet(ChangeSet changeSet)
   at System.Web.DomainServices.DomainService.Submit(ChangeSet changeSet)
   at System.Web.Ria.Services.ChangeSetProcessor.Process(DomainService domainService, IEnumerable`1 changeSetEntries)
   at System.Web.Ria.Services.SubmitOperationBehavior.SubmitOperationInvoker.InvokeCore(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
```

Comment: what SQL connection string does your server use?? I almost assume it might be using "server=.\SQLExpress" since that's the default for SQL Server Express.....

Comment: That was it.  On the machine in question, I was using Developer Edition which installs as MSSQLSERVER.  On another machine with a SQL Server Express installation it worked straightaway.  I had tried to point it to the MSSQLSERVER instance but a connection string mistake had derailed me.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the aspnetdb database created by running aspnet_regsql.exe against a SQL Server instance called SQLExpress - this can be found in the LocalSqlServer connection string in machine.config.  Or by replacing the LocalSqlServer connection string with something that points to your SQL instance.  Something like this:

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
     connectionString="Data Source=YOURCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with machine.config
Go to
[Silverlight-TV-51-Debugging-and-Deploying-WCF-RIA-Services](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-51-Debugging-and-Deploying-WCF-RIA-Services)

then do this:

In IIS under Windows 7, Select the application pool and then "advanced settings." Under "process model" find "Load User Profile" and set it to true.

SQL should now load under the default app pool account.