# Where are user credentials persisted to when creating a Silverlight Business Application Template project?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

The Business Application Template in Silverlight 4.0 generates authentication and user management (add user) features.  Where is the info stored ?  I presume it goes back to the server and then I have my pick on the server side - AD, LDAP, SQL Server, etc. ?  Is this correct ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the answer to [What DB required to make the Silverlight Business Application template work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965700/what-db-required-to-make-the-silverlight-business-application-template-work)

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449(v=VS.91).aspx) may also be helpful.

Comment: Hey kevinw, thanks!  These are excellent resources and it's answered my question.

Comment: My pleasure.  Delighted it was useful.